# MongoDB indexes not working when executing $elemMatch

Tags: mongodb

I am executing an query using $elemMatch and it seems like it is not using the index I added for that.

Here is my document:

```
{
  "_id" : "123466",
  "something" : [ 
        {
        "someID" : ObjectId("5701b4c3c6b126083332e66f"),
        "tags": 
        [
            {
            "tagKey": "ErrorCode",
            "tagValue": "7001"
            }, 
            {
            "tagKey": "ErrorDescription",
            "tagValue": "nullPointer"
            }
        ],
        "removeOnDelivery" : true,
        "entryTime" : ISODate("2016-04-04T00:26:43.167Z")
    }
  ]
}
```

Here are the indexes I am using (I intended to use only first index but I added additional indexes to investigate why none of them are working).

```
db.test.createIndex( { "something.tags:" : 1 }, { sparse : true, background : true } )
db.test.createIndex( { "something.tags.tagKey:" : 1 }, { sparse : true, background : true } )
db.test.createIndex( { "something.tags.tagValue:" : 1 }, { sparse : true, background : true } )
db.test.createIndex( { "something.tags.tagKey:" : 1, "something.tags.tagValue:" : 1 }, { sparse : true, background : true } )
```

Here is my query and response:

```
db.test.find({"something.tags": { $elemMatch: { "tagKey" : "ErrorCode", "tagValue" : "7001" } } } ).explain()

{
    "cursor": "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey": false,
    "n": 2,
    "nscannedObjects": 2,
    "nscanned": 2,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans": 2,
    "nscannedAllPlans": 2,
    "scanAndOrder": false,
    "indexOnly": false,
    "nYields": 0,
    "nChunkSkips": 0,
    "millis": 0,
    "server": "some_server",
    "filterSet": false,
    "stats": {
        "type": "COLLSCAN",
        "works": 4,
        "yields": 0,
        "unyields": 0,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "advanced": 2,
        "needTime": 1,
        "needFetch": 0,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "docsTested": 2,
        "children": []
    }
}
```

Comment: Which server version? Looks like a 2.6.x series result. Note that there are only 2 documents in the collection so the planner probably just figures a collection scan is good enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this was a typing mistake. Your createIndex query has `:` at the end of index name. Just correcting that may get the results you want.

However, it is not necessary that the winning plan always choose the one using index. If COLLSCAN is cheaper, which may be the case in case of collections with less number of elements, Mongo may choose COLLSCAN.

If you want to force index usage, you may use .hint("index_name").

I tried with proper index name without `:` in name and it used index to query. Your results may be different depending on the collection statistics and server version as @Neil Lunn mentioned in comments .

```
db.test.createIndex( { "something.tags.tagKey" : 1 }, { sparse : true, background : true } )
```

And Explain results,

```
db.test.find({"something.tags": { $elemMatch: { "tagKey" : "ErrorCode"} } } ).explain()


{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "test_db.test",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "something.tags" : {
                "$elemMatch" : {
                    "tagKey" : {
                        "$eq" : "ErrorCode"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "something.tags" : {
                    "$elemMatch" : {
                        "tagKey" : {
                            "$eq" : "ErrorCode"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "something.tags.tagKey" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "something.tags.tagKey_1",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : true,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 1,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "something.tags.tagKey" : [
                        "[\"ErrorCode\", \"ErrorCode\"]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },

    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Yes, **but** you are running this on a 3.x series server. The query optimizer does different things in different versions. You can tell the question is using a 2.6.x series by the `"filterSet"` in the output.

Comment: Yes. You are right, and thank you for the hint about "filterSet". I could learn something new.

Comment: Thank you guys. Yeah the : was not intended.